# Customising Cisco Clientless VPN Password Change Screen ASA5525

Tags: cisco, cisco-asa

I'm working with one of the network engineers to customise our login screens for the Cisco clientless VPN, which, apart form time consuming, has been fine (knowledge gap on both of our parts). As part of the initial login routine for first time users, they need to reset their password.

The password change screen (`password_new.html`) displays a message about password strength which we need to alter, but we can't seem to find anything in the documentation about how to configure this screen.

I wondered if anyone knew from where it pulls the information, or can the `password_new.html` file itself be directly modified?